# Is there a way to add a list of references/literature to ASCII-DOC (or Markdown)?

Tags: reference, markdown, pandoc, asciidoc

It's hard for me to keep track of all different markdown-flavours. So I decided to switch to Ascii-doc, since it provides lot more useful features than the base-markdown (see: http://powerman.name/doc/asciidoc).

One feature that I'm really missing is the definition of references/literature-lists. Is there a way to use e.g. bibTex-files and include references to your text?

Are there some kind of plugins for ascii-doc?

Or migh `pandoc` help?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like the [bibliography](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#user-biblio) in asciidoctor?

```
_The Pragmatic Programmer_ <<prag>> should be required reading for
all developers.

[bibliography]
- [[[prag]]] Andy Hunt & Dave Thomas. The Pragmatic Programmer:
  From Journeyman to Master. Addison-Wesley. 1999.
- [[[seam]]] Dan Allen. Seam in Action. Manning Publications.
  2008.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pandoc [supports citations](http://pandoc.org/README.html#citations), even from an external BibTex file. You will need to specify a bibliography file using the bibliography metadata field in a YAML metadata section, or `--bibliography` command line argument. The pandoc markdown syntax is basically:

```
my text [see @smith04]
or @smith04 says blah.
```